# Search query doesn't return anything in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am working on elasticsearch. I created and indexed json file content in elasticsearch.Now am trying to search text using search query.When i try to execute the below query in elasticsearch, it doesn't return anything in the result. But values are in it. Because i checked using the curl command,it return result.

I executed **elasticsearch query** command

```
ES_HOST = {"host":"xxx.xx.xx.xx","port":"9200"}
ES_INDEX = 'sugan'
ES_TYPE = 'doc'

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST])

res = es.search(index=ES_INDEX,body={"query":{"match_all":{}}})

when i print **res**, it's response like below

Search Response:'{u'hits': {u'hits': [], u'total': 0, u'max_score': None}, u'_shards': {u'successful': 1, u'failed': 0, u'total': 1}, u'took': 1, u'timed_out': False}'

 for hit in result['hits']['hits']:
    print "results:"
    print (hit["_source"])
```

it doesn't call the for loop. I don't know why

It doesn't return anything

I executed **curl** command

```
curl -XGET 'xxx.xx.xx.xx:9200/sugan/_search?'
```

It's getting proper result

Comment: Can you show how you are setting up your `es` client in your Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is "port" as string

```
ES_HOST = {"host":"xxx.xx.xx.xx","port":"9200"}
```

It should be:

```
ES_HOST = {"host":"xxx.xx.xx.xx","port": 9200}
```

This is the needed python code (**you need to replace host_ip with your host IP**)

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es =  Elasticsearch(hosts = [{"host" : host_ip, "port" : 9200}])
ES_INDEX='sugan'
es.search(index=ES_INDEX,body={"query":{"match_all":{}}})
```

Comment: yes, already i have done that. I just metioned the syntax for you to come to know that. But i didn't get the result

Comment: please copy/paste your 4 lines of python - just to make sure that you don't have any typo.

Comment: @PythonTeam : I think that I found you bug... the port was defined as string instead of int

Comment: I changed like as you said. Now also am not getting the result.

Comment: try running again the "curl" command, to make sure that the elasticsearch server is up. and try both, your code with port = 9200, and the 4 lines of code in my answer (modify the value of host_ip). Those 4 lines are working for me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113500/discussion-between-yaron-and-python-team).